# Why cant save the hover state after unhover my drop-down menu?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, tailwind-css

I've tried to create a mega-menu which has two drop down menu, one of them works well(unfortunatly it has to; because the unhover state won't save).
Now the other drop down contains a menu which has two other drop down menu too.
If i want to click the third drop down menu ,i can't because as soon as i unhover the parent element the state disappears.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: Pacifico;
            src: url(./fonts/Pacifico-Regular.ttf);
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family: Exo;
            src: url(./fonts/Exo2-VariableFont_wght.ttf);
        }
        body{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .drop-menu{
            visibility: hidden;
            opacity: 0;            
            transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .hover-product:focus + .drop-menu{
            visibility: visible;   
            opacity: 1;                  
        }  
        .drop-menu-2{
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        .software:hover + .drop-menu-2{
            visibility: visible;
            
        }  
       
        .cat-detail-1{
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        .main-drop-1:hover + .cat-detail-1{
            visibility: visible;
        }
        .cat-detail-2{
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        .main-drop-2:hover + .cat-detail-2{
            visibility: visible;
            
        }
        .active{
            background-color:red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="flex justify-between bg-yellow-200 relative top-5">
        <li>
            <p style="font-family: Pacifico;">Logo</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="hover-product">Products</a>
            <div class="drop-menu flex bg-gray-200 rounded-2xl left-0 absolute w-[95%] ml-10 mt-5" style="font-family: Exo;">
                <img src="./img/female_shopping_from_phone.jpg" alt="Pic" class="w-1/4 h-80 p-3 rounded-3xl">
                <div class="w-3/4 flex pt-10 leading-10">
                    <div class="cat-detail w-1/3 text-center">                          
                        <div>  
                            <a href="#" class="block font-bold text-2xl mb-5">Laptops</a>                                            
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3  hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8 " >Asus</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Lenovo</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">HP</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">MSI</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Dell</a>
                        </div>                   
                    </div>
                    <div class="cat-detail w-1/3 text-center ">                       
                        <div>
                            <a href="#" class="block font-bold text-2xl mb-5">Mobile</a>                       
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Samsung</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Iphone</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Xiaomi</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">HTC</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Huawei</a>
                        </div>                   
                    </div>
                    <div class="cat-detail w-1/3 text-center">                       
                        <div>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out font-bold text-2xl mb-5">PC Hardware</a>                       
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Graphic card</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">CPU</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Ram</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">SSD</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Mother Board</a>
                        </div>                   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="software">Software</a>
            <div class="drop-menu-2 w-[35%] bg-gray-200 absolute left-[55%] flex justify-around p-7 mt-5 rounded-2xl" style="font-family: Exo;">
                <div class="">
                    <a href="#" class="font-bold main-drop-1">Adobe</a>
                    <div class="cat-detail-1  absolute -ml-[3%] mt-5 bg-red-400 p-5 rounded-xl">    
                        <div class="mb-3 leading-8">
                            <p class="font-bold">sec1</p>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Lorem</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Lorem</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Lorem</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="leading-8">
                            <p class="font-bold">sec2</p>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Lorem</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Lorem</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Lorem</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="#" class="font-bold main-drop-2">Microsoft</a>
                    <div class="cat-detail-2  absolute -ml-[3%] mt-5 bg-red-400 p-5 rounded-xl">    
                        <div class="mb-3 leading-8">
                            <p class="font-bold">sec1</p>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Lorem</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Lorem</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Lorem</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="leading-8">
                            <p class="font-bold">sec2</p>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Lorem</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Lorem</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Lorem</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button class="w-32 h-10 rounded-3xl bg-indigo-400 text-white hover:bg-indigo-500 focus:bg-indigo-600 focus:ring-4 duration-200" style="font-family: Pacifico;">Login</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is from `class="software"` till end.
Note that I've tried some javascript code like `mouseover` listener but didn't work.

Comment: You left a gap between your "Software" menu item, and the submenu. When the mouse cursor is in that gap, then "Software" _won't_ be in its :hover state any more, and therefor the submenu disappears, before you can get to it. I made them both visible and added a dotted red outline to each here, so you should be able to clearly see the space where the problem occurs: https://jsfiddle.net/8jkq4oc0/ You need to eliminate that gap, so that the mouse cursor can pass from "Software" to the submenu, without "falling into a hole" on the way.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, But what about the third dropdown menu?which has p tag with "sec1" text. It also disapear after unhover it. It neither hasn't any gap left

Comment: That is _exactly_ the same issue ... https://jsfiddle.net/46atz19r/ _"It neither hasn't any gap left"_ - yes, it has. The link you are hovering to trigger the submenu, is only as big as its text content "Adobe" requires. The gray background area of that whole submenu is _not_ what triggers the sub-sub-menu to show, _only_ your tiny link is.

Comment: @CBroe I really appreciate the time you are spending to solve this.But I got other problem.I tried to add padding to the software element so it's box got bigger. and i guess i eliminetaed the gap but still as i unhover the software the hover box disapear.

Comment: Then I would suggest you use your browser dev tools, to investigate the issue further. You can "set" elements into the :hover state there, so that they will show the styles that apply then, without actually having to hover the elements with your mouse. And then check if there really are no gaps any more, on the path that you are moving the mouse cursor from the sub-menu point to the sub-sub-menu.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use like this**

```css
.drop-menu, .child-dropdown-menu{
            visibility: hidden;
            opacity: 0;            
            transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
            z-index: 11;
            transform: translateY(20px);
            transition: all ease 0.3s;
        }
        
        .dropdown-item:hover .drop-menu, .child-dropdown-item:hover .child-dropdown-menu  {
            visibility: visible;
            transform: translateY(5px);
            opacity: 1; 
            z-index: 1;
        }
        
        .align-items-center {
            align-items: center;
        }
    
        .active{
            background-color:red;
        }
```

```html
  <ul class="flex align-items-center justify-between bg-yellow-200 relative top-5">
        <li>
            <p style="font-family: Pacifico;">Logo</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="hover-product">Products</a>
            <div class="drop-menu flex bg-gray-200 rounded-2xl left-0 absolute w-[95%] ml-10 mt-5" style="font-family: Exo;">
                <img src="./img/female_shopping_from_phone.jpg" alt="Pic" class="w-1/4 h-80 p-3 rounded-3xl">
                <div class="w-3/4 flex pt-10 leading-10">
                    <div class="cat-detail w-1/3 text-center">                          
                        <div>  
                            <a href="#" class="block font-bold text-2xl mb-5">Laptops</a>                                            
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3  hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8 " >Asus</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Lenovo</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">HP</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">MSI</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Dell</a>
                        </div>                   
                    </div>
                    <div class="cat-detail w-1/3 text-center ">                       
                        <div>
                            <a href="#" class="block font-bold text-2xl mb-5">Mobile</a>                       
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Samsung</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Iphone</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Xiaomi</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">HTC</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Huawei</a>
                        </div>                   
                    </div>
                    <div class="cat-detail w-1/3 text-center">                       
                        <div>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out font-bold text-2xl mb-5">PC Hardware</a>                       
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Graphic card</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">CPU</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Ram</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">SSD</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Mother Board</a>
                        </div>                   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item">
            <a href="#">Software</a>
            <div class="drop-menu w-[35%] bg-gray-200 absolute left-[55%] flex justify-around p-7 rounded-2xl" style="font-family: Exo;">
                <div class="child-dropdown-item">
                    <a href="#" class="font-bold ">Adobe</a>
                    <div class="child-dropdown-menu  absolute -ml-[3%] mt-5 bg-red-400 p-5 rounded-xl">    
                        <div class="mb-3 leading-8">
                            <p class="font-bold">sec1</p>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Lorem</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Lorem</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Lorem</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="leading-8">
                            <p class="font-bold">sec2</p>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Lorem</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Lorem</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Lorem</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="child-dropdown-item">
                    <a href="#" class="font-bold main-drop-2">Microsoft</a>
                    <div class="child-dropdown-menu  absolute -ml-[3%] mt-5 bg-red-400 p-5 rounded-xl">    
                        <div class="mb-3 leading-8">
                            <p class="font-bold">sec1</p>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Lorem</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Lorem</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Lorem</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="leading-8">
                            <p class="font-bold">sec2</p>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Lorem</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Lorem</a>
                            <a href="#" class="block hover:transition hover:ease-in-out hover:-translate-x-3 hover:underline hover:decoration-in hover:decoration-indigo-500 hover:decoration-2  hover:underline-offset-8">Lorem</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button class="w-32 h-10 rounded-3xl bg-indigo-400 text-white hover:bg-indigo-500 focus:bg-indigo-600 focus:ring-4 duration-200" style="font-family: Pacifico;">Login</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
```